# How to parse database entry "12" into date format as "12" not "0"

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing

In my android app, I am reading the time 12.00 from a SQLite database. Then, I combine it with other strings before parsing everything in a specific date format. However, after parsing, my time is always corrupted and the digit 12 get parsed as 0.

Here is my code:

```
public static long timeInMs(Cursor c) {

 String timeAsString = null;
 Date timeFormated = null;
 long timeInMs;

 timeAsString = c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(7);

 try {
        timeFormated = CheckDate.dateformat_1().parse(
                timeAsString);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    timeInMs = timeFormated.getTime();

return timeInMs;
}
```

how can I solve this out ?

Comment: I can't see the error from the code you have posted, but in general: you would store the date/time as a Unix-timestamp of type long, then you won't have any problems parsing it

Comment: @Droidman  The code itself doesn't contains any error. It reads and parse everything fine. It's just this issue with the digit 12 when parsing. But what is Unix-timestamp of type long ? is it different data type ? and how to define a variable as Unix-timestamp of type long ?

Comment: @duffymo .. it works now .. changing my dateformat_1 from hh.mm to HH.mm .. Thanks .. please put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "12:00" means "midnight", then parsing it to "0:00" is correct for 24 hour clock. You want am/pm.